# How can we inject external background knowledge into data stream mining algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, real-time

If we want to include the context as a background knowledge, how can we do this when using a data stream mining algorithm. What are the possible forms of the background knowledge and how can they be integrated in real time?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a very broad question and is not likely to get very useful answers. Do you have a specific dataset or domain you are considering? Are you performing classification or clustering?

Comment: I'm doing outlier detection .